# iAd: How to simulate errors?

Tags: iphone, iad

In my didFailToReceiveAdWithError I want to hide iAd banner and show banner from other ad provider.

How do I simulate error call?

Note: closing the internet connection is not an option since I still need it for the other ad provider.

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get errors regularly when running a test config. The service does this intentionally to help you test. You can also just call your didFailToRecieveAdWithError method from your didRecieveAd method.

Comment: how do you run a test config?

Answer (score 4):

Go into your settings -> Developer -> fill rate under iAd settings and select 0%.